# WebSocket connection failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: gunicorn, flask-socketio, eventlet

I have Flask application and I want to use flask-socketio to handle webosockets with gunicorn and eventlets.

Although, when I try to connect my test client (http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) I am receiving:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/socket.io?encoding=text' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`

socketio_app.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app, port=9090, host='0.0.0.0', async_mode='eventlet', debug=True)

@app.route('/socket.io')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

and I run it in this way:

```sh
gunicorn -k eventlet -w 1 socketio_app:app -b 0.0.0.0:9090 --error-logfile - --access-logfile - --log-level debug
```

Should I use it in another way? Should I manually modify my response like that?

```py
@app.route('/socket.io')
def index():
    return Response(status=101, headers={
        'Connection': 'Upgrade',
        'Upgrade': 'websocket'
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a WebSocket client to connect to a Socket.IO server. Use a Socket.IO client and you will be fine. WebSocket is not the same as Socket.IO, the latter is implemented on top of WebSocket and uses a different protocol.

Comment: So how can I use flask-socketio with websockets? According to documentation: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#requirements eventlet can be used with websockets.

Comment: Websocket is used internally by the Socket.IO protocol. If you want to use native Websocket then you have to use a Websocket web server, not a Socket.IO server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Miguel.